# Get certain values in a specific line of a file in C++

Tags: c++, file, while-loop

i have a text file looks like this:

```
 Volume in drive D is New Volume
 Volume Serial Number is 6A13-D37C

 Directory of D:\

12/19/2019  10:21 PM    <DIR>          C and C++
12/19/2019  10:35 PM                 0 file.txt
12/17/2019  10:00 AM    <DIR>          My stuff
11/01/2019  08:42 AM    <DIR>          Python
               1 File(s)              0 bytes
               3 Dir(s)  116,699,697,152 bytes free
```

i want to get those "month/day/year" value on screen and finish by printing out the earliest date.
Here is what i had done so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int month, day, year;
    int min_month, min_day, min_year;
    char skip;
    string skip_line;
    ifstream file;
    file.open("file.txt");

    if (file == NULL)
        cout << "Unable to open";
    else
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) // skip the first 5 lines
            getline(file, skip_line);

        //get the first month/day/year
        file >> min_month;
        file >> skip;
        file >> min_day;
        file >> skip;
        file >> min_year;
        cout << min_month << "/" << min_day << "/" << min_year << endl;
        getline(file, skip_line);

        for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) //loop here to get other mm/dd/yy
        {
            file >> month;
            file >> skip;
            file >> day;
            file >> skip;
            file >> year;
            cout << month << "/" << day << "/" << year << endl;
            getline(file, skip_line);

            // compare to get the true earliest date
            if(min_year < year)
                continue;
            else if(min_year > year)
            {
                min_year = year;
                min_month = month;
                min_day = day;
            }
            else //min_year == year
            {
                if(min_month < month)
                    continue;
                else if(min_month > month)
                {
                    min_year = year;
                    min_month = month;
                    min_day = day;
                }
                else 
                    if(min_day > day)
                    {
                        min_year = year;
                        min_month = month;
                        min_day = day;
                    }
            }

        }
        cout << "The earliest date is: " << min_month << "/" << min_day << "/" << min_year << endl;
    }
}
```

the program above ran fine, but i want to ask:
Is it ok to use those `getline(file, skip_line);` to skip to lines we want ? is there any way more efficient to get these values without using `file >> skip;` to ignore "/" character between them ? **Most important, The for loop i use to get other mm/dd/yy will not work with other files with more dates. Can i use while loop here ? what will be the condition for it ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it ok to use those getline(file, skip_line); to skip to lines we want ?

With text files you don't really have a choice, you don't know the byte offset of a given line in advance so you can't just seek to it, you have to read it looking for the newlines. You could optimise it a bit if searching for a small fragment in a very large file, but not really in a case like this.

> is there any way more efficient to get these values without using file >> skip; to ignore "/" character between them

hmm, there are plenty of ways to do such file IO a lot more efficiently, but I don't think it is an issue here. More so if your trying to read gigabytes at a drives max speed, especially keeping up with modern NVMe on large datasets.

> to ignore "/" character between them

`file >> skip` is one way to handle it, to be stricter you might check that `skip` contains the expected value (e.g. `'/'`).

> Most important, The for loop i use to get other mm/dd/yy will not work with other files with more dates. Can i use while loop here ? what will be the condition for it ?

To handle the number of lines, one way is to attempt to parse every line. In the case of `>>` you could read each line into a string then `std::stringstream` and try to parse that, and check the fail state:

```
while (std::getline(file, line))
{
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    int month, day, year;
    char skip;
    ss >> month >> skip >> day >> skip >> year;
    if (!ss.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Year " << year << " month " << month << " day " << day << std::endl;
    }
}
```

```
Year 2019 month 12 day 19
Year 2019 month 12 day 19
Year 2019 month 12 day 17
Year 2019 month 11 day 1
```

Another option is to use regular expressions:

```
std::regex date_regex("^(\\d{2})/(\\d{2})/(\\d{4}) ");
std::string line;
while (std::getline(file, line))
{
    std::smatch match;
    if (std::regex_search(line, match, date_regex))
    {
        std::cout << "Year " << match[3] << " month " << match[2] << " day " << match[1] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

---

Note, this looks like the output from the `dir` command. Be very careful that such outputs can vary with other system settings, for example it took me several moments to realize you had `month/day/year`.